# ValueError: gets without cas behavior in pylibmc

Tags: python, memcached, pylibmc

I'm trying to use the `gets` and `cas` methods from pylibmc(v1.5.2) to interact with the memcached server. As [documented](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/reference.html), we should pass the cas token from `gets` to `cas`.

```
token = mc.gets("key_python_1")
mc.cas("key_python_1", "value_python_1_new", token)

# Or
mc.cas("key_python_1", "value_python_1_new", mc.gets("key_python_1"))
```

However, I got a `ValueError: gets without cas behavior` err which is hard to understand.

Could someone shed some light on this issue? Any working example will be appreciated. Thanks ;)

--- Update ---

This is how I get `mc`.

```
import pylibmc

mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True, behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True, "ketama": True})
```

Comment: please mention the value of mc

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR Updated :)

Comment: print mc after this steps and see what it contains

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you just need to add "cas": True to the list of behaviors.

```
import pylibmc

mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True, behaviors={"cas": True, "tcp_nodelay": True, "ketama": True})
```